# Calibrate overscan settings

Tags: hdmi, config.txt

There are [options to adjust the the overscan settings](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt#Video_mode_options) in `/boot/config.txt`.

```
# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=0

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16
```

Is there any way for me to "test" the `overscan_*` settings instead of manually editing the config file, restarting the system, checking if the settings need adjusting more, then restarting until all the settings fit nicely with my monitor?

Comment: I'm hoping there is some sort of application that has screens such as _"Press the left or right arrows until the entire box is inside of the screen"_.

Comment: Check this article
[Overscan settings in Raspberry Pi](http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/28/raspi-display-setting.html)

Answer (score 8):

I used the following to calibrate my display https://github.com/ukscone/set_overscan

I found this on http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=305797&sid=4fe5fc284854fe3723841f79ea2c6546#p305797