# RPi Model B 512 MB--FreeBSD--text running off screen

Tags: boot, setup, composite-video, config.txt, freebsd

I am having a problem with FreeBSD, wherein I cannot get the text to be constrained within the area of a TV (composite).  I have been using framebuffer_height and framebuffer_width in /boot/msdos/config.txt to get the right size but overscan_left, _right, etc. does not seem to be consistent.  The size of the TV screen is approx. 11.5 wide  x 8.5 high (inches).  There are no real controls on the TV for the size of the viewing area as far as I can tell.  The TV is manufactured in 1985, it is a Montgomery Ward TV.

Everything else with this **FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-arm-armv6-RPI-B.img** image seems to work fine.  It seems with this image I cannot extract the ports tree but I had done that earlier with another image.

I have also tried using a config.txt generated from a debian system on the same TV, which set the framebuffer at 720x480 and the overscan settings all at 16, the only other thing in the file was disable_overscan=0... that was not commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know FreeBSD but I used the following to calibrate my display on Raspbian

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/23104/8697

Comment: The script referenced looks to be a useful tool although I don't think it will work on FreeBSD.

Comment: @eh-five `overscan.c` is actually the meat of that; it looks to be POSIX and should at least compile on FreeBSD.  It's all just about the creation of a dev node and an `ioctl()` call -- which may or may not be linux specific, but if you know someone else running FreeBSD with a good grasp of system programming they might get a good clue from that. The script would probably work too (for creating the dev node, etc.) except it uses `whiptail` which is a bit of an oddity.  However, the script itself is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Well, the problem really seems to be that I get no response from using the overscan settings, rather I get a change but not really predictable.  The screen will be garbled in the initial stages with some settings although when I get to the login prompt it will be clear.

Comment: I think the problem is that the settings are rather unusual. I found trying to do them manually didn't produce the results I wanted (and it was SLOOW). If you can't get this to work on FreeBSD, you could try on Raspbian and copy settings. Have you set `sdtv_mode` `sdtv_aspect`

Comment: I agree, many layers of interpretation it seems. Of the video information.  I have tried sdtv settings, the most success I had was with solely framebuffer settings.  I was thinking that I should take the settings from a raspi-config generated config.txt too.   @miliways, thanks

Comment: I was directed to the proper solution:  overscan_scale=1    fixes the issue and overscan settings are used.  a5'