# Video output not centered on TV screen

Tags: hdmi, output

I've had a few issues with HDMI.  The first was no audio which I fixed.  I suspect this other issue can be fixed in a similar fashion, but I am a super NOOB to all of this.

Basically, the image on my TV is right justified, with one thick black bar of nothingness on the left side of the screen.  While not a huge problem, it has become a tad annoying.  Any idea how to fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`overscan` would most likely fix this issue. See [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23094/calibrate-overscan-settings). And the [official docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md). Basically, `overscan` fine tunes the image size. You can change the overscan more precisely by editing `config.txt` but you shouldn't need to. But if you need to, check the [official docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md) for `config.txt`. You would want to add/edit the parameter `overscan_left=` and set it equal to something smaller, just mess with the number and see what works best.

Comment: Thanks!  Interesting you mention this.  I was fixing an unrelated issue (no audio) and stumbled across the overscan options under the same config.txt.  I changed the overscan_bottom= because text had also been cut off a bit at the bottom.  Interestingly, the bottom one worked while the left one did nothing.  Not sure why...

EDIT:  I read your comment too fast the first time.  Just noticed you said to change it to a *smaller* number...I was going larger, so that may be the reason.  I'll give that a try.