# 'Zoom out' on 3.5 inch LED screen

Tags: raspbian, display, led, screen

I bought a 3.5" LED screen that is on my Pi, however it is nearly impossible to use because edges of windows are clipped off etc.

How can I 'zoom out' so that all the windows are really tiny? Basically so I can fit the entire display on the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XRandR panning.

First , determine the display names.

```
xrandr -q
```

Then setup the panning itself :

```
xrandr --output DISPLAYNAME --mode 640x480 --panning 1920x1080
```

Use this to restore the normal mode :

```
xrandr -s 1920x1080
```

Answer (score 1):

`overscan` would most likely fix this issue. See [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23094/calibrate-overscan-settings), and the [official docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md). Basically, `overscan` fine tunes the image size. You can change the overscan with `sudo raspi-config` or you can change the overscan more precisely by editing `/boot/config.txt` but you shouldn't need to. But if you need to edit `/boot/config.txt`, check the [official docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md) for `config.txt`. You would want to add/edit the parameters `overscan_left=`, `overscan_right=`, `overscan_top=`, `overscan_bottom=`  and set them equal to something bigger, just mess with the number and see what works best.

Comment: I don't think overscanning is the issue. I think the screen is simply too small to show the windows in their entirety.

Comment: @Jacobm001 oh, my understanding was that the display was not fitting properly, I see what you're saying now after rereading the question.

Comment: So how can I shrink the windows?

Answer (score 0):

You’re dealing with a completely different piece of hardware. The main problem with using a pi pico . Is the memory buffer size. Since you can’t even fit the full screen into the tiny memory of the pico, you have to resort to working on the screen in sections the only way to create any decent code to fit is to split the screen into four horizontal bands each containing 1/4 of the buffer size, so as you can guess you can forget, animations in fullscreen or videos .

Comment: Where do you find that the OP uses a Raspberry Pi Pico?

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  Pico isn't mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score -3):

startx -- -dpi xx
Try different xx settings for your display

Comment: Why is there a blank `--` in your command? What does `-dpi xx` do? Someone who isn't familiar with this command may not understand what values of `xx` to try, or how they relate to the output.

Comment: The OP was having trouble with the GUI and therefore he uses this command. The double dash is used to say the following commands are driver commands.

Comment: My point is that such information would be good to include in the answer.

Comment: I intentionally don't explain the full details. I have found that you learn more and remember more if you look things up yourself.