# Fit contents of screen to small display

Tags: display

I am displaying Raspberry Pi OS on a 3.5" display. The windows do not fit in the screen.

Is there a way I can shrink the entire image on-screen so that everything is smaller but fits on-screen? The smallest display resolution offered by the Raspberry Pi configurations menu is 640x480 I believe. Can I custom edit a configuration file, or install software the allows for a different resolution
?

Or, is there a way to get a moving window on-screen to look around at the full contents of the desktop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual resolution + scrolling?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95738/virtual-resolution-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

Try using xrandr to setup a virtual desktop with panning.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=51907