# Calibrate the screen for shell sessions

Tags: raspbian, screen, osmc

While I certainly [want my ssh access to work](https://superuser.com/questions/1091051/cant-login-with-putty-to-raspi-3-osmc), for now I'm put back to accessing the shell directly using the wireless keyboard.

Unfortunately, the edges are cut: I don't see the first and last two rows and leftmost three columns in the shell screen.  I have calibrated the screen in Kodi, and even decreased the visible size, but this is obviously strictly a Kodi thing and doesn't affect the text terminal at all.

Is there some way to rectify this?

- OSMC 2016.05-1
- RasPi 3
- connected to a FullHD tv set via HDMI

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23094/calibrate-overscan-settings): After setting `disable_overscan=0` in `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting, the text terminal is usable.